# The general statically linked libraries in Linux

Tags: linux, hyperlink, static-libraries

Given a static library StaticLib, how to know in advance which compiler and linker options and libraries to use in linux? There are some programs that shows dependencies but I think no one gives specific options for a specific compiler. Something like StaticLib depens on Lib1, Lib2 and Lib3, so use the options -x -y -x for gcc.

There are in Stackoverflow and in the Internet, thousand of specific questions that would be answered automatically just by answering this general question.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie This is not correct - static libraries are not dynamic executables and therefore don't have dynamic dependencies.  E.g.  

    $ file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a: current ar archive
    $ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
 not a dynamic executable

Answer (score 1):

Static libraries don't have explicit dependencies on libraries - unlike dynamic libraries, which do (and whose dependencies you can see with `ldd` on a Unix-like platform).  You can use `nm` to look at which symbols are defined, undefined, etc. within the library, and that will give you some information.  There is no single answer to the question "which library contains the definition for the symbol that my library references but is undefined?" since any library with a definition for that symbol is as valid as any other to the linker.  (This is also true with dynamic libraries - the dependencies advertised by them are just guides to the linker.)

As for compiler flags, there is no universal way to determine which flags to use to link with a given library, since various compilers will either strip out this information from the resulting library/executable in certain cases, or just never record it in the first place.  Developers will usually advertise this information out of band alongside their libraries, e.g. "to link against this library, use flag XXX".